# Put .jpg photos in app's App folder to use DBRoulette

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, dropbox

I downloaded sample project from www.dropbox.com/developer.In that sample drop box is connected but random photos doesn't loaded to drop box.It display alert message such as "Put .jpg photos in your app's App folder to use DBRoulette".In which folder i put photos.Kindly tell about me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you need to keep some photos in your Dropbox account under pothos folder which sample project is trying to fetch.

Try this and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

/Users/XXX/Dropbox/Apps/YorAppName/kick.jpg - exactly right path for "samplecode".